# Python---TypeError: Battery.get_range() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

Main program-

```
"""A class that can be used to represent a car."""

class Car:
"""A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year 
        self.odometer_reading = 0
    
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formative descriptive name."""
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()
    
    def read_odometer(self):
        """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
        print(f"This car has {self.odometer_reading} miles on it.")
    
    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """
        Set the odometer reading to a given value.
        Reject the change if it attempt to roll the odometer back.
        """
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
    
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")
    
    def increment_odometer(self, miles)  :
        """Add the given amount to the odometer."""      
        self.odometer_reading += miles

class Battery:
"""A simple atytempt to model a battery for an electric car"""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=70):
        """Initialize the battery's attributes"""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
        
    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the size of the battery."""    
        print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery.")
    
    def get_range(self):
        """Print a statement about the range thgis battery provides."""
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range = 260
        elif self.battery_size == 100:
            range = 315
    
        print(f"This can go about {range} miles on a full charge.")

class ElectricCar(Car):
"""Models aspects of car, specific to electric vehicle."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """
        Initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        Then initialize attribute specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()

secong program-

from car import ElectricCar

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)

print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())

my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()

my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

Output

```
2019 Tesla Model S
This car has a 75-kWh battery.
This car can go about 260 miles on a full charge.
```

Comment: I have a completely different error. Please provide your actual code. (In your code the battery size is 70, not 75 as your output suggests). But if you change the default value of battery size from 70 to 75, the code works for me without an error.

Comment: Thanks man, that was the issue! as soon as I changed that 70 to 75 everything was good.
I did wrote my actual code and the output I wrote was what I was hoping to get.

Comment: As for the error in the title, you probably wrote `Battery.get_range()` which does not work since an class instance is needed, e.g. `Battery().get_range()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Battery class `def __init__(self, battery_size=70)`, you initialized battery_size = 70.

To get your desired output `This car can go about 260 miles on a full charge.`, set battery_size = 75. So it should look like this:

```
    def __init__(self, battery_size=75):
        """Initialize the battery's attributes"""
        self.battery_size = battery_size
```

This is because of the conditionals here

```
    def get_range(self):
        """Print a statement about the range thgis battery provides."""
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range = 260
        elif self.battery_size == 100:
            range = 315
```

You never checked for battery_size = 70 in your get_range method. You can add an else clause to check for other values other than 75 or 100.